# Is there a high-quality, open-source version of the Stable Diffusion model equipped with ControlNet that I can use right now and not be disappointed?

Tags: image, stable-diffusion

I have been surfing Hugging face and GitHub and trying out different models for virtual try-on, but none of them are satisfactory. What I need is a model that can combine a picture of a person and a picture of a clothing item and generate a picture of this person wearing this item.
Any recommendations?

None of the models I've tried offer a realistic outcome - the majority of them have poor image in the end - stained and chaotic.

Answer (score 1):

AI is not there yet.

You could train a model on your shirt and your person and combine the two by including both key words but it's not going to look exactly the same.